# Apache .htaccess to use subfolder as root

Tags: .htaccess

I know this kind of question is recurrent. But after several hours of searching I didn't find anything.

I'm making a website using Slim. However, in their documentation, they use `/public` as root directory, which I don't want. I want the website root to be `/`. Quite concerned about security, I created a `.htaccess` to redirect `http://www.example.com/` to `http://www.example.com/public/`, so no user can reach `/src` and other folders :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ /public [P]
</IfModule>
```

This causes a problem : the URI remains `/public/`, therefore the `public/index.php` file below returns a 404 error :

```php
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello world!");
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

I have to replace `'/'` with `'/public/'` in the code for the page to work. I don't exactly like that.
What should I add to Slim's `/public/.htaccess` below to remove the `/public` from the URI ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

## Edit: Solution used

I redirected my vhost to `/public/`. The web hosting service I use supports this, so it's the best solution.

#### Thanks to MrWhite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteRule ^$ /public [P]
> </IfModule>
> ```

This only "forwards" requests for the root / homepage, ie. `/`, not `/foo`, etc. This also forwards the request using mod_proxy (as a *reverse proxy*), whereas you only need a simple *internal rewrite*.

You need to rewrite *every* request that would otherwise go to the root directory (outside of `/public`) to the `/public` subdirectory. ie. `/foo` rewrites to `/public/foo` and `/images/bar.jpg` to `/public/images/bar.jpg`, etc.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

(No need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper since mod_rewrite is mandatory here, it's not optional.)

All your URLs (to everything) should then omit the `/public` subdirectory.

**UPDATE:** However, it would seem that the `BASE` environment variable is still being set to the `/public` subdirectory by the following directives in `/public/.htaccess`:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
> RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
> ```

You could simply comment out (remove) the above directives and hardcode the `BASE` env var:

```
SetEnv BASE /
```

However, it's unclear whether this would be a problem or not in the Slim framework. It's possible that this is being used to construct URLs (although it shouldn't, since this is the *filesystem* path, not the URL-path by which users access the pages - and can easily be calculated in PHP anyway).

---

Alternatively, everything in `/public` should be in your document root (ie. your *public* directory... `public_html` or `htdocs` etc.) then the `/src` (and other folders) will naturally be outside the document root and no additional directives / `.htaccess` files required to root the request. (Although not every shared server may give you access to above the document root - although they should.)

Or, simply change the `DocumentRoot` to `/public` in your server config.

Comment: I still get the /public everywhere instead of a proper re-rooting. I'll try the alternative solution, apparently my host allows that.

Comment: You need to make sure that `/public` is not present in any of your URLs, including URLs to static resources (CSS, JS, images, etc). The above is an _internal rewrite_ (not a "redirect") so it shouldn't expose the `/public` subdirectory. Also, make sure you've cleared your browser cache.

Comment: Ah, the "problem" would seem to be that `BASE` is being set to `/public` - which is perhaps being used to construct your URLs (thus exposing the subdirectory). I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've tried the alternative solution (setting the vhost to point to /public directly). It didn't even work, the URI kept becoming "/public/...". I just tried commenting the 2 lines in the .htaccess, but I get a 500 error. I don't even understand how the bare Slim skeleton can not work correctly (I didn't even code anything until now).

Comment: "commenting the 2 lines in the .htaccess" - and using `SetEnv BASE /`? And by commenting, you used `#`? If you get a 500 error, check the servers error log for details.

Comment: I'm currently loosing my mind. I reverted to the semi-functional state, but this time I get a 404 instead of the wrong URI... Also I get 500 if I try anything else. I'm going to try a desperate move : the configuration I used on an older project (there have been updates of some packages since then).

Comment: That desperate move half worked. I'm back to the URI being "/public/", but there's no error anymore.

Comment: OK so... The alternative solution does work. I just had a bug that would force the use of the browser cache. *sigh*